# Find string between reoccurring substrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string similar to

```
s = "(test1 or (test2 or test3)) and (test4 and (test6)) and (test7 or test8) and test9"
```

I'm trying to extract between (),

```
['test1 or (test2 or test3)', 'test4 and (test6)', 'test7 or test8']
```

I have tried

```
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ("(", ")"), s).group(1)
result =(s[s.find("(")+1 : s.find(")")])
result = re.search('((.*))', s)
```

Comment: if you change it a bit, it will certainly work.

Comment: `re` module doesn't support nesting. not the good tech

Comment: Since `or` and `and` are also Python keywords, have a look at [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Comment: Doesn't look like you're escaping the parentheses, which you might have to do. Does `r'\((.*)\).*'` work when you do `re.findall()` with it?

Comment: Using `re.findall()` with `r'\((.*)\).*` returns the string inside the first and last bracket.

Comment: If you are attempting to parse expressions, regex is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have *nested* parentheses. That calls for parsing, or if you don't want to go that far, back to basics, parse character by character to find the 0-nesting level of each group.

Then hack to remove the `and` tokens before if any.

The code I've written for this. Not short, not very complex either, self-contained, no extra libs:

```
s = "(test1 or (test2 or test3)) and (test4 and (test6)) and (test7 or test8) and test9"

nesting_level = 0
previous_group_index = 0

def rework_group(group):
    # not the brightest function but works. Maybe needs tuning
    # that's not the core of the algorithm but simple string operations
    # look for the first opening parenthese, remove what's before
    idx = group.find("(")
    if idx!=-1:
        group = group[idx:]
    else:
        # no parentheses: split according to blanks, keep last item
        group = group.split()[-1]
    return group

result = []

for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if c=='(':
        nesting_level += 1
    elif c==')':
        nesting_level -= 1
        if nesting_level == 0:
            result.append(rework_group(s[previous_group_index:i+1]))
            previous_group_index = i+1

result.append(rework_group(s[previous_group_index:]))
```

result:

```
>>> result
['(test1 or (test2 or test3))',
 '(test4 and (test6))',
 '(test7 or test8)',
 'test9']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to make a rough parser for this it would look some like this.

This uses the `scanner` method of pattern objects, iterates through and builds the list when at level 0, where the level is defined through the left and right brackets encountered.

```
import re

# Token specification
TEST = r'(?P<TEST>test[0-9]*)'
LEFT_BRACKET = r'(?P<LEFT_BRACKET>\()'
RIGHT_BRACKET = r'(?P<RIGHT_BRACKET>\))'
AND = r'(?P<AND> and )'
OR = r'(?P<OR> or )'

master_pat = re.compile('|'.join([TEST, LEFT_BRACKET, RIGHT_BRACKET, AND, OR]))

s = "(test1 or (test2 or test3)) and (test4 and (test6)) and (test7 or test8) and test9"

def generate_list(pat, text):
    ans = []
    elem = ''
    level = 0
    scanner = pat.scanner(text)
    for m in iter(scanner.match, None):
        # print(m.lastgroup, m.group(), level)
        # keep building elem if nested or not tokens to skip for level=0,1
        if (level > 1 or
          (level == 1 and m.lastgroup != 'RIGHT_BRACKET') or
          (level == 0 and m.lastgroup not in ['LEFT_BRACKET', 'AND'])
        ):
            elem += m.group()
        # if at level 0 we can append
        if level == 0 and elem != '':
            ans.append(elem)
            elem = ''
        # set level
        if m.lastgroup == 'LEFT_BRACKET':
            level += 1
        elif m.lastgroup == 'RIGHT_BRACKET':
            level -= 1
    return ans


generate_list(master_pat, s)
# ['test1 or (test2 or test3)', 'test4 and (test6)', 'test7 or test8', 'test9']
```

To see how `scanner` behaves:

```
master_pat = re.compile('|'.join([TEST, LEFT_BRACKET, RIGHT_BRACKET, AND, OR]))
s = "(test1 or (test2 or test3)) and (test4 and (test6)) and (test7 or test8) and test9"

scanner = master_pat.scanner(s)
scanner.match()
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='('>
_.lastgroup, _.group()
# ('LEFT_BRACKET', '(')
scanner.match()
# <re.Match object; span=(1, 6), match='test1'>
_.lastgroup, _.group()
# ('TEST', 'test1')
scanner.match()
# <re.Match object; span=(6, 10), match=' or '>
_.lastgroup, _.group()
# ('OR', ' or ')
scanner.match()
# <re.Match object; span=(10, 11), match='('>
_.lastgroup, _.group()
# ('LEFT_BRACKET', '(')
scanner.match()
# <re.Match object; span=(11, 16), match='test2'>
_.lastgroup, _.group()
# ('TEST', 'test2')
```